# introducir una array de datos en otro array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda. Mi duda es la siguiente. Estoy recuperando unos datos del back para repesentar en un grafico ng2charts. Recupero de la tabla los datos a traves de un bucle for of. Me devuelve los datos pero despues los intento meter en el array del datos del chart y solo me representa el último par de datos del array. Los datos de una columna se guardan en en una variable y los datos de otra columna se guardan en la otra variable.

```
getData() {
    for (let value of this.riskArray) {
        var impactResult = value.IMPACT_RESULT;
        var probResult = value.PROB_RESULT;
        console.log(impactResult, probResult); // Recupero los datos del back
    }

    this.bubbleChartData[0].data = [
        { x: impactResult, y: probResult, r: 20 }, // sólo me recoge el ultimo dato de cada columna.
    ];
}
```

MODIFICACION DEL CÓDIGO

```
  {
    data: [
      { x: 10, y: 10, r: 10 }, //valor por defecto 
    ],
    label: 'Series A',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderColor: 'blue',
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'purple',
    hoverBorderColor: 'red',
  },
];

getData(getData) {
  const data = getData;
  this.riskArray = data.data;
  const dataChart = [];

  for (let value of this.riskArray) {
    dataChart.push({x: value.RISK_IMPACT_RESULT, Y: value.RISK_PROB_RESULT, r: 20})

  }

  this.bubbleChartData[0].data = dataChart;
  console.log(this.bubbleChartData)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas declarando las variables en cada iteración del `for-of` y el formato que espera `data` es un array con objetos que tengan esta forma `{x:1, y: 1, r: 3}`.

Puedes crear un array inicial fuera del loop y ir haciendo el push de los datos en dicho array.

```
getData() {
    const data = [];
    for (let value of this.riskArray) {
        data.push({x: value.IMPACT_RESULT, y: value.PROB_RESULT, r: 20 })
        // console.log(impactResult, probResult); // Recupero los datos del back
    }

    this.bubbleChartData[0].data = data;
}
```

Comment: Gracias!! Me ha servido para meter esos datos en el this.bubbleChartData[0].data = dataChart; pero no se por qué motivo no se representan en la gráfica. Haciendo console.log() si me salen los datos pero en la gráfica no se representa nada. Además de eso, en el console.log() desaparece el valor por defecto del array({ x: 10, y: 10, r: 10 }). pUEDES VER COMO LO HE PUESTO ARRIBA EN EL CÓDIGO. GRACIAS!!!

Comment: @Robertosanchezfigueroa de nada. El valor por defecto se pierde porque estas asignando un nuevo valor `this.bubbleChartData[0].data = dataChart`. Creo que no te sale nada porque tienes un tipo en tu codigo `dataChart.push({x: value.RISK_IMPACT_RESULT, Y: value.RISK_PROB_RESULT, r: 20})` la `Y` está en mayuscula y deberia ser minuscula.

Comment: era por la y, la p*** madre ...jajaja Como se nota que aun soy junior jajaja Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! un saludo

Comment: de nada. A todos nos ha pasado alguna esto.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estás declarando las variables cada vez que se hace una iteración y por esto te queda siempre el último valor. Declara las variables antes de for. Si estás variables son arrays entonces la asignación que estás haciendo es errónea, debes usar 
ImpactResult.push( value.IMPACT_RESULT)
probResult.push(value.PROB_RESULT)

De esta manera estás ingresando cada valor del array en otro array. Tendrías que verificar si es el formato que requiere tu gráfica, pero creo que con esto solucionas tu inquietud.

Comment: De la manera que me comentas no puedo asignar esas variables (que son arrays) a "X" e "Y" , me dice que las variables del tipo [] no son asignables a x e y. Gracias por la ayuda